# Como habilitar input text com input radios?

Tags: javascript

Não estou sabendo fazer a função JS para habilitar o campo text com o input radio.

Tem como alguém me ajudar?

```
@foreach($p->telefones()->get() as $key => $t)
<div class="col-md-6" id="telefone_div_{{($key + 1)}}">
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        {!! Form::label('telefone_2', 'Telefone:' ,['class' => 'bot']) !!}      
        {!! Form::text('telefone_2[]', mask($t->telefone_2,'(##)####-#####'), ['class'=>'form-control tels', 'readonly' => 'readonly', 'data-campo'=> $key])!!}

        <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-success">
            <input type="radio" name="options" data-campo="{{$key}}" > Editar 
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-danger">
            <input type="radio" name="options" data-campo="{{$key}}"> Remover
        </label>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Qual input você quer habilitar?

Comment: O que você entende por "habilitar o campo text com o input radio"?

Comment: Quero habilitar o input text criado com o Blade do Laravel.